# When does the EDT start?

Tags: java, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I was wondering when does the event dispatch thread start in Java.

1. Is it the main thread, or is it started in `Window/Frame` constructor?
2. Is it started by `JVM` if it detects usage of `AWT/Swing`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: What difference will it make to your life when you find the answer?

Comment: I will feel satisfied that I learned something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main thread is not the EDT thread. EDT thread (and some another related threads) is started automatically when the first GUI event is posted (for example: you show first window or you use the method `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`). For more info see the class `EventQueue`.